# How to register domain using OVH API

Tags: api, dns, ovh

I have problem with registering a domain using API OVH. In first step I create cart with:
**POST /order/cart**
Then I check if domain is available:
**GET /order/cart/{cartId}/domain**
If it is, than I add it to cart with: 
**POST /order/cart/{cartId}/domain**
And I dont know what to do next?
How to confirm and order a cart?
Which method I should use?

Or maybe there is another way to register domain using diffrent methods?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but I'm starting to search the information because I want to implement it and looks like you have to call to the configuration endpoint (POST `/order/cart/{cartId}/item/{itemId}/configuration`) and then perform the checkout (POST `/order/cart/{cartId}/checkout`) as far as I can see.